# How to configure the JSON response when using rocket pants?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json, api, rest

I am using rocket pants to render my JSON API.

I'm trying to change the way it renders the JSON by overriding as_json in my model, but somehow, it seems not to change anything in the rocket pants response.

in my controller:

```
class Api::V1::ProjectsController < RocketPants::Base
  ...
  def show
    expose Project.find(params[:id])
  end
  ...
end
```

And in my model:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def as_json(options = {})
    {"this" => "is not working!"}
  end
  ...
end
```

What am I missing?

Comment: i never heard of rocket-pants, but isn't it ```to_json``` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've figured out how to do that. The way rocket pants work is by looking at the `serializable_hash` method. Overriding it results in a change in the response.

**Edit:**

The solution I got to:

In the model where I need to add some attributes: simply override the attributes method:

```
 # Overriding this method is required for the attribute to appear in the API
  def attributes
    info = {} # add any logic that fits you

    super.merge info
  end
```

In the controller that needs to expose the API I've created a new Model class (this is only needed in order to keep different API versions), and overridden the serializable_hash method:

```
  class Location < ::Location 
    def serializable_hash(options = {})
      super only: [:id, :lat, :long],
            include: [user: {only: ...your attributes here...}]
    end
  end
```

Comment: any chance you could provide some examples as the documentation for rocket-pants is a little lacking on this.

Comment: I've added details in the answer.

Answer (score 8):

In addition, there is a first set of options that can be sent to the expose block. Depending on the source, you can pass options through to serializable_hash method. For example:

`expose user, only: [:name, :email]`

This will call serializable_hash on the object with name and email.

You can also specify eager loading in this set of options. For example:

`expose uploads, :include => { :user => { :only => :username } }`.

This will expose your uploads and eager load the belongs_to association with user.

Source: https://github.com/filtersquad/rocket_pants/issues/20#issuecomment-6347550

Answer (score 0):

For nested things:

`paginated @matches, include: { listing: { include: { company: { only: [:name, :email] } } } }`